# Mercurial go back n revisions before the current one

Tags: mercurial

In mercurial how can I go back `n` revisions from the revision I'm currently on?

This answer shows how it can be done in git: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16739578/1696114, `git checkout HEAD~n`.

If there isn't a way to go back `n` revisions, is there a way to go back just to the parent revision (i.e. one revision back)?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `HEAD~n`, use `.~n`.

`hg help revisions` shows you Mercurial's revision specifiers.

The Mercurial equivalent of Git's `HEAD`/`@` is `.`, and the Mercurial equivalent of Git's `~number` is ... `~number`

Like Git, Mercurial also supports the `^` suffix, with the same meaning: `^` followed by a number is the *number*-th parent.

Omitting the number gets you the first parent, or steps back 1 first-parent (which gets you the first parent), so `.^` or `.~` gets you the first parent.  Note that some Windows command line interpreters like to use `^` for their own purposes so that you may have to quote them.